# Grab the title from the properties of the Word document in Windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I want to grab the title of the Word document from its properties in Windows form application and store it in a string. As shown in the picture. How to do this using C#?

[image: As show in the picture]

Comment: Here a useful link for you [Extracting Microsoft Office Application Properties without automation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/erikaehrli/2005/11/30/extracting-microsoft-office-application-properties-without-automation/), but your lack of effort to solve the problem is really upsetting. Next time do you research before asking a _gimme teh codez_ question

Comment: Use the Word COM interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title like this you may have to include an additional ddl file for the packaging stuff. Right click on References and add reference to WindowsBase under Framework to use packaging.

```
Package file = Package.Open(@"C:\Users\pamjl\Desktop\Code\New Microsoft Word Document.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
String yourTitle = file.PackageProperties.Title;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the DocumentFormat.OpenXml nuget package to your project, and a reference to WindowsBase.

With this import:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
```

This will retrieve the title:

```
var filePath = ""; // path to your .docx file
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
    var title = document.PackageProperties.Title;
}
```